# Using Word2vec with Tensorflow on Windows

Tags: python, windows, tensorflow

In [this tutorial file](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/tutorials/embedding/word2vec.py#L45) by Tensorflow the following line is found (line 45) to load the word2vec "extension":

```
word2vec = tf.load_op_library(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)), 'word2vec_ops.so'))
```

I am using Windows 10, and as also is pointed out in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42106032/tensorflow-word2vec-error), `.so`-files are for Linux.

What is the equivalent extension to load on Windows?

Also, I don't understand why so much else is included in Tensorflow upon installation but Word2Vec has to be built locally. In documentation, [Installing TensorFlow on Windows](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_windows), there is no mention of having to build these extensions.

Was this an old practice that has now changed and everything is shipped with the installation? If so, how does that change apply to the `word2vec` module in the example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it has changed! Tensorflow now includes a helper function, `tf.nn.embedding_lookup` that makes it very easy to embed your data.

You can use it by doing something like [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/word2vec), i.e.

```
embeddings = tf.Variable(
    tf.random_uniform([vocabulary_size, embedding_size], -1.0, 1.0))

nce_weights = tf.Variable(
  tf.truncated_normal([vocabulary_size, embedding_size],
                      stddev=1.0 / math.sqrt(embedding_size)))
nce_biases = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([vocabulary_size]))

# Placeholders for inputs
train_inputs = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, shape=[batch_size])
train_labels = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, shape=[batch_size, 1])

embed = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(embeddings, train_inputs)

# Compute the NCE loss, using a sample of the negative labels each time.
loss = tf.reduce_mean(
  tf.nn.nce_loss(weights=nce_weights,
                 biases=nce_biases,
                 labels=train_labels,
                 inputs=embed,
                 num_sampled=num_sampled,
                 num_classes=vocabulary_size))
# We use the SGD optimizer.
optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate=1.0).minimize(loss)

for inputs, labels in generate_batch(...):
  feed_dict = {train_inputs: inputs, train_labels: labels}
  _, cur_loss = session.run([optimizer, loss], feed_dict=feed_dict)
```

The full code is [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.2/tensorflow/examples/tutorials/word2vec/word2vec_basic.py).

In general, I would be hesitant to rely too much on the `tensorflow/models` repo. Parts of it are quite out of date. The main `tensorflow/tensorflow` repo is better maintained.